# (Mercurial) Is there any way to go back and mark the start of a branch?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I foolishly failed to start a branch off the `default` trunk to do some experimental work, and now realize that what I've done isn't really all that great. Since this code is actually used by others (and out in the wild), I want to mark revision `394` (the last change not made in this experiment) as the proper head, and basically strip off anything I've done). What would be the best way to do that?

```
@ 397 my change, bad (tip)
|
|
o 396 my change, bad
|
|
o 395 my change, bad
|
|
o 394 good change
|
|
...
```

This should become

```
@ 394 good change (tip)
|
|
|- 397 bad change (closed)
||
||
|o 396 bad change
||
||
|o 395 bad change
|/
|
...
```

Do I need to make a dummy check-in based off of 394 (which would create a new head automatically)? That seems the simplest solution, but not the "cleanest".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a dummy check-in, but you do need to make sure your next check-in is done from rev 394.

```
hg update -r 394
<do work>
hg commit
```

The new head will be the tip.

---

Alternatively, if you haven't pushed the repo anywhere[1], and you just want to delete those revisions forever you can use the mq extension, and either `strip` the changesets or `qimport` them into a patch queue and `qdel` the patches.

```
hg strip 395                   # Will strip rev 395 and it's descendants
```

This is dangerous, make sure you get it right.

---

[1] If you've already sent the changesets anywhere, too late, the cat's out of the bag. You'll just have to branch off rev 394.

Comment: *hg up - hg branch dead-branch - hg co - hg rebase path* is better for creating modigied DAG. Removing history also can be done with histedit extension

Comment: Yeah, the cat's already out of the bag. What I wanted to know was if there was some way to say "treat 394 like the current tip". In order to fix this mess, I ended up making one new push, which I based off of 394. I then closed the other head.